# any way to reduce long query in Apex class

Tags: apex, soql, query, customsetting

I have below query which is checking profile permissions .is there any way if this query can be shortened..like using custom label in SOQL or Custom Setting

```
[SELECT profile.name FROM Profile where profile.name=:profileName and
                                       (PermissionsPrivacyDataAccess=true or
                                        PermissionsAuthorApex=true or
                                        PermissionsConnectOrgToEnvironmentHub=true or
                                        PermissionsManageNetworks=true or
```

Comment: Since you are matching by name remove the rest of conditions and check for them in logic. Don’t forget to add them to the query. Then you can iterate through queries fields and check for them to be true if they are Boolean values

Comment: (That wouldn't really shorten the query though as the various permissions would have to be added to the list of fields to return.)

Comment: TBH I don't think you can actually shorten the over-all code length if you are wanting to check that the profile has at least one of the specified permissions. NB: if you are trying to determine whether the current user has at least one of those permissions, you should also check their assigned permission sets. See https://gist.github.com/jkentjnr/599d6df0332e7fa6efb493b8156ddac3 for some handy code for that.

Comment: @PhilW right but it would significantly shorten the query execution. I think I read it wrong with long as in runtime

Comment: @Eric, you may have actually understood it right - only sandy can say :)